# Surfacelistbox Drag Drop (Stop Rotate!?)

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, pixelsense

I have implemented drag drop functionality to a surfacelistbox as explained here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727837.aspx). It's the exact same code I have.

I was wondering if it's possible to access a CanRotate property somewhere to stop the visual a user has when dragging rotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeginDragDrop returns a SurfaceDragCursor which has a CanRotate property you can set to false

Comment: Robert you've been extremely helpful today. I've been pulling my hair out with some of these problems and I seriously appreciate your feedback mate. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @DanielMcNulty - you're welcome :)  I designed the SurfaceDragDrop APIs during my time at Microsoft and know they can be a bit confusing to get started with